# First connect fails for specific host

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, networking, remote-desktop, rdesktop

I am using rdesktop to connect to a Windows 7 desktop with RDP. I am using the command: `rdesktop -g 1800x1000 win3.int.mtak.nl`. The first time I run this command after a reboot of the client (Ubuntu 13.04, rdesktop 1.7.1) I get the error:

```
ERROR: win3.int.mtak.nl: unable to connect
```

When I run the command immediately after, it works fine. I have no issues connecting to other hosts. I also tried `host win3.int.mtak.nl` before connecting with rdesktop and it returns the right IP address. When I try to connect from another Windows client, it doesn't give any errors.

I found the following using strace:

```
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = 0
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 0)    = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLOUT}])
syscall_307(0x4, 0x7ffff081f360, 0x2, 0x4000, 0, 0x1c, 0x5, 0x5, 0x5, 0x5, 0x5, 0x5, 0x5, 0x5, 0x5, 0x5, 0x5, 0x5, 0x5, 0x5, 0x5, 0x5, 0x5, 0x5, 0x5, 0x5, 0x5, 0x5, 0x5, 0x5, 0x5, 0x5) = 0x2
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000)  = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
ioctl(4, FIONREAD, [120])               = 0
recvfrom(4, "Y\324\205\200\0\1\0\1\0\2\0\2\4win3\3int\4mtak\2nl\0\0\1"..., 2048, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 120
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 1, 4981)  = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
ioctl(4, FIONREAD, [80])                = 0
recvfrom(4, "\361\326\205\200\0\1\0\0\0\1\0\0\4win3\3int\4mtak\2nl\0\0\34"..., 1928, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 80
close(4)                                = 0
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) = 4
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(3389), sin_addr=inet_addr("10.100.0.63")}, 16) = -1 EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
```

The system gives a EHOSTUNREACH unreach error, even though there is a route to the host:

```
mtak@frisbee:~$ netstat -rnv
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.137.1   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.100.0.0      10.100.1.1      255.255.255.0   UG        0 0          0 tun0
[other output omitted]
```

So in summary:

- For only one host in the subnet I get a EHOSTUNREACH error when connecting
- I can connect other hosts in that subnet on the first attempt
- This only happens the first time I try to connect, or after waiting for a very long time.
- Subsequent connection attemts work fine

The RDP server is running on VMware ESX, just like all the other servers in the subnet. There are no specific settings for the network interface.